# python3-config is missing on Mac

Tags: python-3.x, pybind11

I am trying to run `python3-config --extension-suffix` as part of using Pybind11 and I keep getting the following error:

```
zsh: command not found: python3-config
```

I tried using python3.8-config but even that does not work. What is the best way to resolve this issue? (I am running this on Mac).

Comment: what python version do you have installed?

Comment: I have python3 installed on /usr/bin/python3

Comment: And the minor version?

Comment: I have 3.8 version on my machine but it doesn't provide python3-config or python3.8-config